# SetSslClientCertPfx does not allow change of file location

Tags: chilkat

I am using chilkat active x to access a webservice secured with **x509**.

> SetSslClientCertPfx("pfxfilewithpath","password")

It works fine with the **pfx** file in the location I used it first.

If I copy it to another path it does not work anymore (*error 109*) , even after pc reboot or renaming.
Any chance to get this to work ?

Thanks in advance
tom

Using **locert.LoadByCommonName("certname")** and **SetSslClientCert(locert)** works but I would prefer to use **SetSslClientCertPfx()**

Answer (score 0):

Examine the contents of the httpObject.LastErrorText property after calling httpObject.SetSslClientCertPfx (assuming this is for HTTP).